# React Native: Make Each Child of ScrollView Full Height

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I have a `ScrollView` which has two children, and I want each of the children to be the full height of the available space on the screen, meaning view 1 fills the whole screen, and then I scroll down to start to see part of slide 2. If I scroll all the way down, I should only see slide 2.

I can't figure out how to get this to happen. What is currently happening is that each child is filling half of the available vertical space, so I don't get any scrolling.

Any ideas how I can achieve this layout? Thanks!

**Current UI:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fljc.png

**Desired UI:**

- Before scrolling: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HOYi.png
- After scrolling all the way down: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfLd5.png

**Code:**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    Text,
    View
} from "react-native";

const Home = () => {return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
        <View style={styles.slide1}>
            <Text>this should be full height</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.slide2}>
            <Text>this should also be full height, but only be visible once i scroll down</Text>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
)};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    slide1: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: "blue"
    },
    slide2: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: "green"
    },
    scrollView: {
        flex: 1
    },
    scrollViewContainer: {
        flexGrow: 1
    }
});

export default Home;
```

Comment: One way is to use ```Dimensions.get("window").height``` as value for property ```minHeight``` for both of your childrens.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев - that would work, except that gives me the entire window height, including the top and bottom nav (via React Navigation). I want the window height minus the navbar heights.

Comment: If count of your slides is known, you could try to set ```minHeight: count * 100 + "%"``` for contentContainerStyle. Then every slide with ```flex: 1``` would have total height of your ScrollView. Of course it applicable only if your navigation bar is outside of this ScrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do what you are trying to accomplish with `flex` layout.

I would suggest getting the `height` of the visible container - either the height of the window or calculate it some other way, [possibly using](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.58/view#onlayout) `onLayout` of the containing view and getting the height there, and then you have to set the height of your two inner views using that. You may need to wrap your `scrollView` in a `View` and use its `onLayout` function instead of the one for the `scrollView`.

To do the second part of your question, `scrollView` has a [snapToInterval](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.58/scrollview#snaptointerval) prop you can set.

Let me know how that goes for you or if you need code examples.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I think you may be correct. I used `onLayout()` to calculate the height of the `ScrollView` and then was able to set the height of my child `View` to the same height.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by using `onLayout()` as Doug Watkins suggested and updating the height of the children to match the height of the parent `ScrollView`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    Text,
    View,
    LayoutChangeEvent
} from "react-native";

class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        slideHeight: 0
    };

    updateHeight = (e: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
        this.setState({ slideHeight: e.nativeEvent.layout.height });
    };

    styles = StyleSheet.create({
        slide1: {
            justifyContent: "center",
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        },
        slide2: {
            justifyContent: "center",
            backgroundColor: "green"
        },
        scrollView: {
            flex: 1
        },
        scrollViewContainer: {
            flexGrow: 1
        }
    });

    render () {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={this.styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={this.styles.scrollViewContainer} onLayout={this.updateHeight}>
                <View style={[this.styles.slide1, {height: this.state.slideHeight}]}>
                    <Text>this should be full height</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[this.styles.slide2, {height: this.state.slideHeight}]}>
                    <Text>this should also be full height, but only be visible once i scroll down</Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: wouldn't it then be fairer if you accepted Doug's answer instead...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) to achieve this functionality. Set your data or component in swiper slides and set props `horizontal={false}` to get vertical sliding.

So, first install [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) using this command:

> npm i react-native-swiper --save

Now, import and use it as following :

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Swiper from "react-native-swiper";
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper style={{}} height={height} horizontal={false}>
      <View style={styles.slide1}>
        <Text>this should be full height</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.slide2}>
        <Text>
          this should also be full height, but only be visible once i scroll
          down
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Swiper>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  slide1: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  slide2: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollViewContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

I know this may not perfect solution, but it work around. Swiper originally made up with scrollview, so there may be not problem.